# Keep on forward song until long button pressed is released

Tags: android, android-button

I have code below to forward song on long button press,but problem is that it only forwards once and does not repeat even though button is still pressed.

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() { 
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            int temp = (int)startTime;
                            if((temp+forwardTime)<=finalTime){
                               startTime = startTime + forwardTime;
                               mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
                            }
                            else{
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                               "Cannot jump forward 5 seconds", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            return true;
}
```

Give me solution so that for long button press song should keep on forwarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click listeners will be triggered just once.

You'll do better implementing *View.OnTouchListener(...)*. With this approach you should detect **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN** and **MotionEvent.ACTION_UP** (see also **MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL**). In between this events you can forward the song and perform additional processing.

**EDIT:** Added details on code

```
boolean forwardSong = true; // this should be a global member
    new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            while(forwardSong){
                //forward your song here
            }
        };
    }.start();
    mButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                forwardSong = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                forwardSong = false;
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps.